# local notification is triggered/fired on not specific or desired time

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I'm trying to add local notification feature to my reminder app, so the app should trigger a notification on saved time in database, but instead it only trigger notification when the reminder view is dismissed and I know why because of `fun viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool)` function, but isn't suppose to be the local notification should be triggered only on specific time which was assigned to `fireDate`, how I can solve this issue?

I'm kinda new to local notification

```
override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {

   createLocalNotification()

}

func createLocalNotification(){

    let localNotification = UILocalNotification()
     localNotification.fireDate = reminders.time!
    localNotification.alertBody = reminders.name!
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)

}
```

Comment: First of all, why do you schedule your `UILocalNotification` in `viewDidDisappear()` func? 
Second, have you debugged your `reminders.time!`? Is the date correct? is the timezone set properly?

Comment: for your first question, because I want the `func createLocalNotification()` to start working in the background once the reminder view is dismissed, to the second question I think `reminder.time!` has no problem I guess

Comment: You need to set your notification timezone before setting the firedate. Make sure you cancel all previous scheduled notifications

Comment: Debug your `reminders.time!`
set your timezone by `localNotification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()`

And replace your `createLocalNotification()` into `viewWillAppear()` at least.

Comment: I just debugged `reminder.time`, it turned out the `16:10` was saved instead of `18:10` as I saved it, though I implemented timeZone.